# How to call Auth::id() in controllers for front end

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, vue.js

I'm trying to call the id of my user in my controllers for my front end. The backoffice Auth::id() works like a charm, but when I try to call it in the controllers for my backoffice I get an error that my user_id cannot be null. Meaning that Auth::id() doesn't seem to work. So it seems like Laravel only recognises a signed in user in the backoffice and I don't know why.

This is the store function of my controller for my front end:

```php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $optionElection = new OptionElection();
        //this returns null
        $optionElection->user_id = Auth::id();
        // this also returns null 
        $optionElection->option = Auth::name();
        $optionElection->votes = 0;
        $optionElection->election_id = $request['election_id'];
        $optionElection->accepted = 0;

        if ($optionElection->save()) {


            return response()
                ->json($optionElection);

        }

    }
```

When I tried to store the data, I always checked that I'm logged in in the backoffice with Laravel Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried `\Auth::id()`. ?
This should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

These helper methods will only retrieve the authenticated user or id if an user is actively logged in and if the controller method is wrapped with the `auth` middleware. If not they'll just return null.

```
\Auth::id();

auth()->id();
```

Comment: they still return null. It's odd because the helpers do work in my backoffice after I log in, but they don't in the frontend (which is also made with laravel controllers)

Comment: @hxwtch can you run `php artisan route:list` and post the result here? I want to check the middleware on the method.

Comment: sure! I uploaded them here: 
https://ibb.co/mAOgiF
              and  https://ibb.co/kH8E3F

Comment: @hxwtch except one api route, no other routes have auth middleware. How you are enforcing the auth?

Comment: I have a function that does this:

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

that's probably the one you mean. How should I enforce my auth?

Answer (score 0):

`$user = auth()->user();`

then

`$optionElection->user_id = $user->id`;

Comment: this gives the error "Trying to get property of non-object"